# Modify this GEPP algorithm to work with matrices

Tags: algorithms, matrices, linear-algebra

I've been stuck with this problem for a day or so, and I really can't figure it out. I need to modify this pseudocode so that it works when b is not just a vector, but a matrix with same number of rows as A.

I understand the idea to basically apply the row operations to the matrix b just as if it were a vector, and then do the back substitution, but I'm having trouble with the indexing and I really can't figure it out.

[image]

Basically, what I need to figure out is modify the algorithm so that b and x are matrices, and they undergo the same element operations